# How to get Priority of C# PriorityQueue element

Tags: c#, priority-queue, .net-6.0

I am initializing a priority queue that stores XY coordinates, prioritized by their euclidian distance from origin. I created a custom `Comparer` that makes this operate as a max heap:

`PriorityQueue<int[], double> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<int[], double>(Comparer<double>.Create((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y)));`

This works great, except sometimes I want to be able to look at the top of the heap using `Peek()`. I can get the value of the element, the point which has type `int[]`, but I can't get the priority. I don't see anything that would allow me to access `TPriority`. Take this use case for example, which is a common usage of heaps to get the top/bottom K elements in a collection:

```
for (int i = k; i < points.Length; i++)
{
    double euclidianDistance = EuclidianDistance(points[i]);
    if (euclidianDistance < EuclidianDistance(maxHeap.Peek()))
    {
        maxHeap.Dequeue();
        maxHeap.Enqueue(points[i], euclidianDistance);
    }
}
```

You will see that I have to compute the euclidian distance again for the element at the top of the heap. Visual Studio shows me this, although I cannot seem to access that second property of type double which refers to the priority.

[image]

Comment: Just store it with the item itself. Perhaps with a value tuple or other some other simple data structure

Comment: I think that defeats the purpose of how priority queues are intended to be used in C# though. I see what you're saying, because I could always use my custom comparer to compare against some value inside of a tuple, but I would have to store that tuple as the value and the priority.

Comment: For instance, when I have a min heap of ints, I just declare the int as the priority and the value itself. For something like this that seems like it would be a great usage of this C# setup with value+priority, it seems like a waste to just encapsulate the value in a tuple and use it as both the element and the value.

Comment: Why not just use TryPeek? Or if it's N elements that you want, a SortedList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that this requires usage of a try/get:

```
for (int i = k; i < points.Length; i++)
{
    double euclidianDistance = EuclidianDistance(points[i]);
    if (maxHeap.TryPeek(out int[] topPoint, out double priority) && euclidianDistance < priority)
    {
        maxHeap.Dequeue();
        maxHeap.Enqueue(points[i], euclidianDistance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use any of the two methods as per your needs

**TryPeek** - if you want to get the value and the priority value without Poping out of the queue.

This method returns false - if the queue is empty otherwise true

```
myHeap.TryPeek(out TElement element, out TPriority priority)

myHeap.TryPeek(out int val, out int priorityval); //for int type
```

**TryDequeue** - If you want to Pop the value along with the priority value.

This method returns false - if the queue is empty otherwise true

```
myHeap.TryDequeue(out TElement element, out TPriority priority)

myHeap.TryDequeue(out int val, out int priorityval); // for int type
```